# Accessing a file path from a Power Platform Plugin

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I am attempting to build a plugin in Power Platform that makes use of a 3rd party library. The problem is that the function I need to use takes a file path parameter and not any sort of byte array, stream, or file object. Is it possible to work with file paths in Power Platform? I've searched on the web and I haven't found a solution to my problem.

The file itself would be stored in a Power Apps table.